# Wamp php calling to same site to download a file

Tags: php, codeigniter, wamp

I'm writing tests for my CodeIgniter site using simpletester.
One of the things that it does is offer autogenerated files.
I want to test if the output of a file is correct.

However, if I do this:

```
function testFunction1(){
    $url = site_url('downloader/function1');
    $handle = fopen($url,'r');
    $contents = stream_get_contents($handle);
    echo $contents;
    fclose($handle);
}
```

It outputs a 404.

It works perfectly when I put "www.google.com" as the url.
I can also download the file if I copy paste the URL in the browser.

Thanks!

edit:
Even if I try to download a regular file (so not a php function), with the full url, it gives the 404.

Comment: Well, does that URL exist? What does `$url` contain?

Comment: site_url() adds the serveraddress and stuff.

Comment: could you put a print_r($url) right before fopen and copy/paste us the output?

Comment: And: is it a local wamp? Is the server address set right? (i.e. http://localhost/)

Comment: I would guess you'll need to add in more logic. I would bet if you tried to do fopen('downloader/function1','r'); it would work OK. i.e skipping the site_url helper for local files.

Comment: We've tried a couple of urls. The simplest one would be: http://localhost/Project1/CodeIgniter/license.txt
It works if called from a browser, but not from the code.

Comment: when your using relative paths, simply remove site_url() for relative path instances.

Answer (score 0):

when your using relative paths, simply remove site_url() for relative path instances.

fopen accepts the following:

```
$handle = fopen("/home/rasmus/file.txt", "r");
$handle = fopen("/home/rasmus/file.gif", "wb");
$handle = fopen("http://www.example.com/", "r");
$handle = fopen("ftp://user:password@example.com/somefile.txt", "w");
```

But site_url seems to be adding something.

also be sure to check the relative path directory is corrent.

Comment: If this were a file, this would be correct. But we want to download a file that is created on the fly, and streamed to the user. So we need to call a php function. Can this be done locally?

Answer (score 0):

If you're accessing locally then just use

```
$url = "main/function":  
$file_content = file_get_contents("http://localhost/codeignitor/" . $url);
```